# Iframe not loading resources with the correct base-href

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, iframe, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a `create-react-app` deployed to `aws cloudfront` with an `API gateway` in front of it (need it to use the `API Keys` with `usage plans`), so this app needs to be loaded into an `iframe` (because its meant to be a widget) and I'm trying this inside another `react` app thats running on `localhost:3000`:

```
<script>
      window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

        fetch("https://my-app-url.com",
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "X-Api-Key": "an-api-gateway-key-that-works" }
          }
        )
          .then((response) => response.text())
          .then((html) => {
            iframe.srcdoc = html;
          });
      });
</script>
<iframe frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

It loads every file (css, js, favicon.ico) inside the `iframe` with status `200 OK` but with the wrong path, so for example, instead of loading:

`https://my-app-url.com/static/js/2.136189ec.chunk.js` (the API Gateway path)

it loads:

`http://localhost:3000/static/js/2.136189ec.chunk.js` (Loads with the local app path)

How can this be fixed? please help me.

EDIT: Is worth mentioning that if I disable the `api gateway` key and load the app like this `<iframe src="https://my-app-url.com"></iframe>`, it works just fine